# Databinding failing in a simple UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, user-controls

Firstly, apologies for all the XAML.  I've tried for a few days to resolve this, but I must be missing something.  The summary question is that my `UserControl` dependency property does not appear to data-bind in the code-behind when it is used.

Details:  I have the following simple `UserControl` (in its own dll), where I am using a slider from 0..59 to choose seconds, and the `UserControl` has a dependency property `Value` that returns a `TimeSpan` made up of the seconds selected via the slider:

```
public partial class TinyTimeSpanControl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public TinyTimeSpanControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private int _seconds;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public int Seconds
    {
        get { return _seconds; }
        set
        {
            if (_seconds == value)
                return;
            _seconds = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Seconds");

            var t = Value;
            Value = new TimeSpan(t.Hours, t.Minutes, _seconds);
        }
    }

    public TimeSpan Value
    {
        get { return (TimeSpan) GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnValueChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TinyTimeSpanControl control = obj as TinyTimeSpanControl;
        var newValue = (TimeSpan)e.NewValue;

        control.Seconds = newValue.Seconds;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "Value", typeof(TimeSpan), typeof(TinyTimeSpanControl), new PropertyMetadata(OnValueChanged));
}
```

With the simple (elided) xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfControlLibrary1.TinyTimeSpanControl"  x:Name="root">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Slider Name="SecondsSlider"
            Width="120"
            Height="23"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            LargeChange="5"
            SelectionStart="0"
            SmallChange="1"
            Value="{Binding Path=Seconds,
                            ElementName=root}" SelectionEnd="59" Maximum="59" />
    <Label Name="label1"
           Grid.Column="1"
           Content="{Binding ElementName=SecondsSlider,
                             Path=Value}" />
    <Label Name="label2"
           Grid.Column="2"
           Content="Seconds" />
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The binding in the control works fine.

Now when I compile this, then add `TinyTimeSpanControl` to one of my windows (elided):

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfControls.MainWindow"
            xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfControlLibrary1;assembly=WpfControlLibrary1"
            x:Name="root"
            Closing="root_Closing">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="142*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <my:TinyTimeSpanControl Name="tinyTimeSpanControl1"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                    Value="{Binding ElementName=root,
                                                    Path=TheTime}" />
            <Label Name="label1"
                   Grid.Column="1"
                   Content="{Binding ElementName=tinyTimeSpanControl1,
                                     Path=Value}" />
            <Label Name="label2"
                   Grid.Column="2"
                   Content="{Binding ElementName=root,
                                     Path=TheTime}" />

        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

where my main window:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private TimeSpan _theTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 33);
    public TimeSpan TheTime
    {
        get
        {
            return _theTime;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_theTime == value)
                return;

            _theTime = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("TheTime");
        }
    }
```

The databinding partially works:

- `tinyTimeSpanControl1` is initially set to the value of `TheTime` property in my code behind of my Main window
- `tinyTimeSpanControl1` updates `label1` when the slider is moved.

But does not work:

- when the slider moves, `label2` remains set to the original version of `TheTime`

Putting a breakpoint in on the `Window_closing` event shows that `TheTime` has not changed.

Am I missing some event that I need to raise in my `UserControl`?

Thanks, and apologies once again for all the xaml (it's the minimal case as well).

Comment: Your code is *really* confusing, first of all, labels are not for simple text display but to label an input control (they have access text support and reference the input element using the `Target` property), use `TextBlocks` instead. Secondly if you just want to display static text next to a bound text you can use `Binding.StringFormat` to add that.

Comment: I'm using INPC to avoid the use of hard-coded events, which is why it might look a little more complex than expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
Value = new TimeSpan(t.Hours, t.Minutes, _seconds);
```

This clears out the binding you established in your window and just sets a value. In the `UserControl` code you should not use `SetValue` but [`SetCurrentValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.setcurrentvalue.aspx), which keeps bindings on the property intact.

Some other things might be off as well that i did not see yet...

Comment: Thanks.  That's half the problem.  The full solution I've just discovered is to add:  `Mode=TwoWay` to the `TinyTimeSpanControl` binding in my main window.  Bumped as your answer helped point me in the right direction.

Comment: Or update code behind to:  `public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
          "Value", typeof(TimeSpan), typeof(TinyTimeSpanControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(TimeSpan.Zero, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnValueChanged));`

Comment: @Barry: Oh yes, the default binding mode is another great source for errors indeed.